# Как совместить табы и фильтрацию элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться почему не работает. При клике должен отображаться контент с картинкой. При клике на all все картинки

```js
function ourAmazingWorksTabs() {
  let tabTitlesWorks = document.querySelectorAll('.our-amazing-work-menu-item')
  let tabsImgs = document.querySelectorAll('.our-amazing-work-img')

  tabTitlesWorks.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', selectTabTitleWorks)
  })

  function selectTabTitleWorks() {
    tabTitlesWorks.forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('active-amazing-work-item')
    })
    this.classList.add('active-amazing-work-item')
    let activeTabTitleWorks = this.dataset.list
    selectTabImgsWorks(activeTabTitleWorks)
  }

  function selectTabImgsWorks(activeTabTitleWorks) {
    tabsImgs.forEach(item => {

      if (activeTabTitleWorks === 'all') {
        item.setAttribute('hidden', 'false')
      } else {
        item.setAttribute('hidden', 'true')
        if (item.dataset.content === activeTabTitleWorks) {
          item.setAttribute('hidden', 'false')
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
ourAmazingWorksTabs()
```

```css
.our-amazing-work-menu-list {
  margin-top: 97px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001);
}

.our-amazing-work-menu-item {
  padding: 14px 15px 13px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 42px;
  color: #717171;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.our-amazing-work-menu-item:first-child {
  padding: 14px 28px 13px 27px;
}

.active-amazing-work-item {
  color: #18cfab;
  border: 2px solid #18cfab;
}

.our-amazing-work-wrapper {
  margin-top: 71px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper:hover .hover-block {
  display: block;
}

.our-amazing-work-img {
  min-width: 285px;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-block {
  width: 285px;
  height: 206px;
  border-top: 6px solid #18cfab;
  background: #e9edef;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  display: none;
}

.hover-img {
  width: 88px;
  height: 43px;
  margin-top: 46px;
}

.hower-block-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #18cfab;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

.hover-block-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #8a8a8a;
}
```

```html
<ul class="our-amazing-work-menu-list">
  <li data-list="all" class="our-amazing-work-menu-item active-amazing-work-item">All</li>
  <li data-list="graphic-design" class="our-amazing-work-menu-item">Graphic Design</li>
  <li data-list="web-design" class="our-amazing-work-menu-item">Web Design</li>
  <li data-list="landing-pages" class="our-amazing-work-menu-item">Landing Pages</li>
  <li data-list="wordpress" class="our-amazing-work-menu-item" active-amazing-work-item>Wordpress</li>
</ul>

<div data-content="graphic-design" class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="our-amazing-work-img" src="./img/graphic_design/graphic-design1.jpg" alt="#" />
  <div class="hover-block">
    <img class="hover-img" src="./img/icon_hower_amazing_work.png" alt="#" />
    <h4 class="hower-block-title">Creative design</h4>
    <p class="hover-block-text web-design">Graphic Design</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-content="landing-pages" class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="our-amazing-work-img" src="./img/landing_page/landing-page1.jpg" alt="#" />
  <div class="hover-block">
    <img class="hover-img" src="./img/icon_hower_amazing_work.png" alt="#" />
    <h4 class="hower-block-title">Creative design</h4>
    <p class="hover-block-text web-design">Landing page</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-content="web-design" class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="our-amazing-work-img" src="./img/web_design/web-design1.jpg" alt="#" />
  <div class="hover-block">
    <img class="hover-img" src="./img/icon_hower_amazing_work.png" alt="#" />
    <h4 class="hower-block-title">Creative design</h4>
    <p class="hover-block-text web-design">Web design</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-content="wordpress" class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="our-amazing-work-img" src="./img/wordpress/wordpress1.jpg" alt="#" />
  <div class="hover-block">
    <img class="hover-img" src="./img/icon_hower_amazing_work.png" alt="#" />
    <h4 class="hower-block-title">Creative design</h4>
    <p class="hover-block-text web-design">Wordpress</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема первая: Вы прописывали атрибут `hidden` тегу с помощью `.setAttribute()`, меняя его значение, а его нужно прописывать с помощью `HTMLElement.hidden = true | false;`
(https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden)

Проблема вторая: `item.dataset.content === activeTabTitleWorks`.
В вашем `item` отсутствует атрибут `content`, ваш `item` — картинка.

Вот рабочий код.

```js
function ourAmazingWorksTabs() {
  let tabTitlesWorks = document.querySelectorAll('.our-amazing-work-menu-item')
  let tabsImgs = document.querySelectorAll('.our-amazing-work-img')

  tabTitlesWorks.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', selectTabTitleWorks)
  })

  function selectTabTitleWorks() {
    tabTitlesWorks.forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('active-amazing-work-item')
    })
    this.classList.add('active-amazing-work-item')
    let activeTabTitleWorks = this.dataset.list
    selectTabImgsWorks(activeTabTitleWorks)
  }

  function selectTabImgsWorks(activeTabTitleWorks) {
    tabsImgs.forEach(item => {

      if (activeTabTitleWorks === 'all') {
        item.hidden = false;
      } else {
        item.hidden = true;
        if (item.parentElement.dataset.content === activeTabTitleWorks) {
          item.hidden = false;
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
ourAmazingWorksTabs()
```

```css
.our-amazing-work-menu-list {
  margin-top: 97px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001);
}

.our-amazing-work-menu-item {
  padding: 14px 15px 13px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 42px;
  color: #717171;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.our-amazing-work-menu-item:first-child {
  padding: 14px 28px 13px 27px;
}

.active-amazing-work-item {
  color: #18cfab;
  border: 2px solid #18cfab;
}

.our-amazing-work-wrapper {
  margin-top: 71px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper:hover .hover-block {
  display: block;
}

.our-amazing-work-img {
  min-width: 285px;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-block {
  width: 285px;
  height: 206px;
  border-top: 6px solid #18cfab;
  background: #e9edef;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  display: none;
}

.hover-img {
  width: 88px;
  height: 43px;
  margin-top: 46px;
}

.hower-block-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #18cfab;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

.hover-block-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #8a8a8a;
}
```

```html
<ul class="our-amazing-work-menu-list">
  <li data-list="all" class="our-amazing-work-menu-item active-amazing-work-item">All</li>
  <li data-list="graphic-design" class="our-amazing-work-menu-item">Graphic Design</li>
  <li data-list="web-design" class="our-amazing-work-menu-item">Web Design</li>
  <li data-list="landing-pages" class="our-amazing-work-menu-item">Landing Pages</li>
  <li data-list="wordpress" class="our-amazing-work-menu-item" active-amazing-work-item>Wordpress</li>
</ul>

<div data-content="graphic-design" class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="our-amazing-work-img" src="./img/graphic_design/graphic-design1.jpg" alt="#" />
  <div class="hover-block">
    <img class="hover-img" src="./img/icon_hower_amazing_work.png" alt="#" />
    <h4 class="hower-block-title">Creative design</h4>
    <p class="hover-block-text web-design">Graphic Design</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-content="landing-pages" class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="our-amazing-work-img" src="./img/landing_page/landing-page1.jpg" alt="#" />
  <div class="hover-block">
    <img class="hover-img" src="./img/icon_hower_amazing_work.png" alt="#" />
    <h4 class="hower-block-title">Creative design</h4>
    <p class="hover-block-text web-design">Landing page</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-content="web-design" class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="our-amazing-work-img" src="./img/web_design/web-design1.jpg" alt="#" />
  <div class="hover-block">
    <img class="hover-img" src="./img/icon_hower_amazing_work.png" alt="#" />
    <h4 class="hower-block-title">Creative design</h4>
    <p class="hover-block-text web-design">Web design</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-content="wordpress" class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="our-amazing-work-img" src="./img/wordpress/wordpress1.jpg" alt="#" />
  <div class="hover-block">
    <img class="hover-img" src="./img/icon_hower_amazing_work.png" alt="#" />
    <h4 class="hower-block-title">Creative design</h4>
    <p class="hover-block-text web-design">Wordpress</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!!!! Работает!!!!!

Comment: @Tati Всегда пожалуйста! Вопрос не забудьте отметить решенным.